# Quickly simplifying the expression 'ite ("a"="b") x y'

Tags: lean

When being left with an expression of the form `ite ("a"="b") x y` which involves a decidable equality between two distinct string literals, it appear that `simp` on its own does not allow me to reduce this expressions to `y`. This is in contrast to the case of `ite ("a"="a") x y` which is reduced to `x` with `simp`. So I find myself doing a case
analysis `cases decidable.em ("a"="b") with H H` and then handling one case using `exfalso` and `dec_trivial` and the other by using `simp [H]`. So I am able to move forward, but I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic and shorter way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `rw [if_neg (show "a" ≠ "b", from dec_trivial)]` or `simp [if_neg (show "a" ≠ "b", from dec_trivial)]` is the easiest way I know.

Comment: As always, than you very much Chris !